# Get Product MPN (Manufacturer Part Number)

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I am working on an SEO app in Laravel. In this app, I am using JSON-LD for every product and I want to show every field recommended by Google's Rich Results Test Or Structured Data Testing Tool.
I have imported my products to my store using CSV files.

The problem is that I want to show MPN number in structured data generated by every product But I can't find any documentation about the MPN number and I don't know how to retrieve this.

I have checked the products JSON but the MPN number field is not available there.

I found [this](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Apps/Populating-Fields-for-the-Google-Shopping-App/m-p/338281#comment-499331) URL and I followed all instructions But I can't fetch the MPN number

I also checked  https://example.com/admin/products/product_id/metafields.json but not succeed.

--------UPDATE--------

In the official documentation of [schema.org](https://schema.org/Product) gives the details about the use of MPN or GTIN number in JSON-LD. I only want to find a way that gives me the MPN or GTIN numbers for any specific product.

Comment: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324482?hl=en

Comment: @Kurt Friars, As I stated in my question I am creating an SEO app. In this app, I only want to get the user's product MPN number for SEO purposes.

Comment: In the documentation I linked to it states "Required for all products without a manufacturer-assigned GTIN" So if they have GTIN, then it is possible the field would be missing no?

Comment: Again I have checked JSON of some products but the MPN and GTIN number fields are not available in Shopify product's JSON.

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/details, GTIN is Barcode. MPN is not an enforced property of a product on Shopify, so you can't guarantee it will be there.

Comment: I know that but I am finding a way of getting that fields.

Comment: You are missing the point of my comment. MPN is not a required field. There is no (reliable/easy/automated) way to build it, if it is missing. Shopify does not mandate products have an MPN.